# WCF prevent server disconnect

Tags: c#, wcf, mono

I have a small client/server application. I was using a hand-coded TCP connection to allow the client to control the server, but now I've converted it to WCF. This saved me a whole bunch of code, but it also gave me a whole new set of problems to fix...

The latest problem is that after a while, the server disconnects the client. I do *not* want this to ever happen, under any circumstances. Currently the client gets about a quarter of the way through its run, and then explodes with fire because the server has dropped the connection. I need to stop this happening.

I was able to write a trivial WCF client/server pair that replicates the problem. It seems that if the client calls a method, waits 15 minutes, and then calls a second method, the second call throws an exception babbling something about the socket having been closed. If I reduce the delay, everything works fine.

I read in another answer somewhere that setting `ReceiveTimeout` should fix this. However, when I tried it, this only fixes the problem under .NET; when running under Mono, it still breaks. Since Mono is the actual target platform, this isn't very helpful.

(Think about SSH - you would *not* want an SSH server to disconnect you just because you didn't type anything for a while. Perhaps you issued a long-running shell command or something... Just because the *server* hasn't received any data from you doesn't mean nothing is happening! It certainly doesn't mean your connection should get dropped...)

All code is C#. The server is a self-hosting console app. The client is also a console app. All configuration is in code. Binding is `NetTcpBinding` with default settings.

What can I do to allow the client to run to completion successfully?

I have a few ideas, but none of them are pretty:

- Manually send heartbeat messages. (Yuck!)
- Detect disconnection and automatically reconnect? (Again, yuck.)
- Turn on "reliable mode". (I'm guessing that since the server *deliberately* ends the session, this won't help.)
- Create one connection per method call. (That's going to be quite a lot of code...)
- Stop using WCF?

Comment: I tried updating from Mono 2.10.9 to Mono 3.2.3 to see if it would make any difference - it didn't. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I "fixed" this by having the client make a new connection for every single command. This works acceptably because the client doesn't send commands all that often. It's annoying having to write the connect/disconnect code a dozen times though...